# How to overlap multiple objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let say I have 3 shapes in illustrator: A, B and C. I would like A to overlap B, B to overlap C and C to overlap A. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You have to "cheat". If it's a simple enough object, I would just duplicate shape C, bring it to the top, and use a Clipping Mask to cover up everything but the intersection.

To do so, create a shape with no fill or stroke around the intersection (can be any shape but I'm using a rectangle for demonstration):

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

Select both your empty shape and the duplicated object that should overlap and do <kbd>Object → Clipping Mask → Make</kbd>

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could achieve this overlapping effect would be to use the shape builder tool. You would create your shapes in the position you would like. I will use the example like @JohnB's.

1. Select all of the shapes that are interacting.
2. Select the Shape Builder Tool. (Shift-M)
3. Click and drag on the areas you wish to overlap. You will notice a
   mesh area like the one in the picture. In the example below I highlighted the areas I clicked and dragged with red arrows.
4. The end result will appear the same as @JohnB's example.

Keep in mind that using this method will break apart the original shapes and you should consider this in case you want to revisit positioning at a later time, etc. In that case @JohnB's approach would best fit because it retains the integrity of the shape within a clipping mask.

[image: Using the Shape Builder Tool]